# How to generate equal amount of different strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this now:

```
var generateIcons = function(playtime, players) {
var count = playtime / 2;
icons = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    if (i % 8 === 0 && players === 8) {
        icons.push("cyan");
    }
    else if (i % 7 === 0 && players >= 7) {
        icons.push("violet");
    }
    else if (i % 6 === 0 && players >= 6) {
        icons.push("orange");
    }
    else if (i % 5 === 0 && players >= 5) {
        icons.push("black");
    }
    else if (i % 4 === 0 && players >= 4) {
        icons.push("gold");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0 && players >= 3) {
        icons.push("red");
    }
    else if (i % 2 === 0 && players >= 2) {
        icons.push("blue");
    }
    else {
        icons.push("green");
    }
}
};
```

The problem is that, I get much more green than blue for example with: `generateIcons(60,4);`
How to get ~equal amount of green, blue, red, gold?

Comment: I know, I could add 5 green, 5 blue, 5 red and after that, shuffle it, but I need in the correct order.

Comment: how would you get an an even amount of green, blue, red and gold? The total length is 30 and you're dividing it by 4. Also post the example of your expected result from your example input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand your problem correctly, this should work:

```js
var generateIcons = function(playtime, players) {
    var count = playtime / 2;
    icons = [];
    colors = ["cyan", "violet", "orange", "black", "gold", "red", "blue", "green"];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     icons.push(colors[i % players]);
    }
    return icons;
};

console.log(generateIcons(60, 4));
```

Comment: Just `icons.push(colors[i % players])` would work too.

Comment: not quite, the resulting array will start with "violet" is you do it like that

Comment: yep, so loop from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Updated my answer, thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Check If that solution satisfies you :)

```
var generateIcons = function(playtime, players) {
            var count = playtime / 2;
            icons = [];
            var randomNumber;

            for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() *  players) + 1); //generate random number from <1, players> probability for each color should be ~equal ;)
                if(randomNumber == 1)
                {
                    icons.push("green");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 2)
                {
                    icons.push("blue");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 3)
                {
                    icons.push("red");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 4)
                {
                    icons.push("gold");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 5)
                {
                    icons.push("black");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 6)
                {
                    icons.push("orange");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 7)
                {
                    icons.push("violet");
                }
                else
                {
                    icons.push("cyan");
                }

            }

        }

generateIcons(60,4);

console.log(icons);
```

Comment: This is great. But Patrick's answer is perfect, because it's (nearly) always equal. If somebody is unlucky, your code can break his heart. ;) Thank you for teaching me a new way to do this!

Comment: "Generating" I always associate with random generatiing. Patrick's solution always generate the same array. It depends what you need :D